# How to access api return object within object for NFT metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, backend

My main issue with the app i'm currently developing is that when a user inputs a search and queries the deep moralis api, i cant access the image of each array in the object.

link to api: https://docs.moralis.io/reference/searchnfts-2

Code:

```
 export const Profile = ({setLoggedIn}) => {
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState([]);
  const [apiQ,setApiQ] = useState("")
  const [nfttei,setNftTei] = useState("")
 async  function getData () {
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': 'SECRET'}};

const data = await fetch(`https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/nft/search?chain=eth&format=decimal&q=${apiQ}&filter=name&limit=10`, options)
const ddata = await data.json()
setProfileData(ddata.result)
  }

  async function handleNftIn () {
   setApiQ(nfttei)
   setNftTei("")
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [apiQ]);
  return (
    <>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: "700", marginTop: 20}}>Profile</Text>
    <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25, fontWeight: "650", marginBottom: 10}}>What NFT collection?</Text>
   <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center"}}>
   <TextInput
   placeholder='type nft keyword'
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#D1D1D1",
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 16,
        width: "60%"
      }}
      onChangeText={(val) => setNftTei(val)}
      value={nfttei}
    />
<AntDesign name="rightcircle" size={30} color="#3A84EC"  onPress={handleNftIn}/>
   </View>
   </View>
    <ScrollView>
    {profileData ? <>
      {profileData.map((el, key) => 
        <View style={{
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          padding: 20,
          borderRadius: 20,
          marginBottom: 20
        }} key={key}>
          <Text key={key}>{el.token_id}</Text>
          <Image source={{
            uri: `${el.metadata.image}`
          }} style={{width: 200, height: 200}}/> 
        </View>
      )} 
      
    </>: null}
      </ScrollView>
      </>
  )
}
```

How can i access the profiledata.metadata.image

on the api docs the result looks like something like this:

```
      "metadata": "{\"name\":\"STEPN APE Realm\",\"description\":\"\",\"image\":\"https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmccQRnTFvhcgB2fsrVM7FQM8g96bthRCn5ejogFJBnyoz\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Accessory\",\"value\":\"STEPN reveal image\"}]}",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse that metadata as it's a JSON string. Something like (excuse any syntax/formatting issues):

```js
{profileData.map((el, key) => {

    const metadata = JSON.parse(el.metadata);

       return <View style={{
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          padding: 20,
          borderRadius: 20,
          marginBottom: 20
        }} key={key}>
          <Text key={key}>{el.token_id}</Text>
          <Image source={{
            uri: `${metadata.image}`
          }} style={{width: 200, height: 200}}/> 
        </View>
}
)}
```

Or simpler:

```
<Image source={{
  uri: `${JSON.parse(el.metadata).image}`
}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}}/>
```